# Sum doesn't return the expected result

Tags: javascript

```js
var cid = [["PENNY", 2], ["NICKEL", 2], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]];

var cur = {"PENNY": 0.01, "NICKEL": 0.05, "DIME": 0.1, "QUARTER": 0.25, "ONE": 1, "FIVE": 5, "TEN": 10, "TWENTY": 20, "ONE-HUNDRED":100 }
    
var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < cur.length; i++) {
    sum += cur[cid[i][0]] * cid[i][1] 
  }
console.log(sum);
```

I have tried many ways like add variable for `cur[cid[i][0]]` and `cid[i][1]` then `console.log` the sum but it still doesn't work. Can somebody tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: learn to debug... console.log is your friend. `console.log(cur.length);` and `console.log(cur[cid[i][0]], cid[i][1], cur[cid[i][0]] * cid[i][1] )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 issues.

- typo in `cid`. should be "ONE-HUNDRED"
- Use `Object.keys(cur).length` instead of `cur.length`. Refer to [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var cid = [["PENNY", 2], ["NICKEL", 2], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE-HUNDRED", 100]];

var cur = {"PENNY": 0.01, "NICKEL": 0.05, "DIME": 0.1, "QUARTER": 0.25, "ONE": 1, "FIVE": 5, "TEN": 10, "TWENTY": 20, "ONE-HUNDRED":100 }
    
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(cur).length; i++) {
  sum += cur[cid[i][0]] * cid[i][1] 
}
console.log(sum);
```